# Best Way To Improve Davinci Resolve 12 Playback Speed?

Tags: mac, davinci-resolve

I run a 2011 MacBook Pro, and it can barely handle Davinci Resolve 12. The biggest problem I have is playback. Playback is very laggy for me, and that is a problem because I need cut and sync clips with the music. Is there a way I can improve the playback speed in Davinci Resolve 12?

Comment: Are you working with RAW files?  I have a [very strong](https://i.imgur.com/BY2HtvB.png) 2014 MBP, but even it still offers glitchy playback.  I don't have an issue with this though, as I'm only doing color correcting/grading and then exporting to Premiere Pro to edit.  If you are having issues trying to edit with your RAW files, I would do the color work first, export your RAW files to a more workable format, then edit with those clips instead.

Comment: @Manly I'm mostly using .mov and .mp4 files, nothing too big. None of them are bigger than 1080p. I also do all the editing in Davinci Resolve, not just the color correction.

Answer (score 1):

Try generating optimized media (i.e. proxy files). Optimized Media is a nice feature that will allow you to playback, edit and grade video files that are optimized for smooth playback, but Resolve will still render from the original video files when you are ready to deliver.

Head over the Media tab and right click on the file(s) you want to optimize, and select "Generate Optimized Media". This may take a little while to run, so grab a coffee while you wait.

You can choose what compression format to use as optimized media (ProRes, DNxHD, etc) by opening Project Settings > General Options.

Here's a nice video tutorial that will walk you through it in more detail:

Comment: In case the video becomes unavailable, could you summarize its content for future readers?

Comment: MichaelLiebman updated :)